# HornetQ RA has it been discontinuted in the latest

Tags: jboss, hornetq

Hi i was going through the api's from jboss for hornetq 
http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/api/index.html

What has happened to the Class HornetQRASessionFactoryImpl and all other classes in the org.hornetq.ra package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing happened, nothing changed. It's on hornetq-ra.jar as usual.

hornetq-ra.rar (the resource adapter) has a file hornetq-ra.jar inside it.

If you just need the class file, you will find it there.

Comment: So do they not mention the api's for it on the link i have provided below. I have seen earlier java docs from 2.2.0 where they specifically mention the apis for RA files but not in the 2.2.5. So let me know if thats not the way i should be interpreting.

Comment: The Resource Adapter is not part of the public API. It's an adapter to be used by the application server. It uses the JCA and JMS APIs. We only publish our API on javadoc. If you need to see JCA's API you have to go to oracle's website. (But I don't really think you need).  You can also download the source code yourself.

Comment: It would be nice to get some vote for the time I spent in answering you? :-)